# Android layout for images

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My requirement is to bring 3 small circles in the bottom of the screen in the middle position..
So,I have done this:--

**footer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dip"
android:background="@color/d_blue"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/rounded" />
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/rounded" />
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/rounded" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

and **@drawable/rounded.xml** is:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval" >
<gradient android:startColor="@color/white" 
android:endColor="@color/white"
android:angle="270"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/l_blue"
android:width="1dp" />
```

But this are not in the middle position..How can I get that 3 small circles in a middle position??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the power of LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:background="@color/d_blue"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
         />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
         />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I hope it will help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dip" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried but,Its not which I want..please see the Biraj Zalavadia's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried but,Its not which I want. please see the Biraj Zalavadia's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in using `RelativeLayout` too. You have used `toRightOf` attribute for both buttons thats why it is not in center. You can try like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot from graphical view of eclipse**

[image: Screenshot from graphical view of eclipse]